# format to send ajax request to chatbase (API.AI)

Tags: ajax, chatbot, dialogflow-es, chatbase

Here is a format example:

Request URL [POST]:
https://chatbase.com/api/message

Sending an Agent message:
Request Body:

```
{
  "api_key": "49448d10-8ca6-4195-8442-2c95b7f1f40c",
  "type": "agent",
  "user_id": "00124248149764",
  "time_stamp": "1481333024000",
  "platform": "kik",
  "message": "I love kittens!",
  "not_handled": true
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "message_id": "6150732209437924",
  "status": 200
}
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: That looks ... fine? If you got a response 200 with a message_id then it's OK. Do you not see your data in the dashboard or something?

Answer (score 0):

I have built a chatbot using this gist. Try this way:

```
function send() {  
            var text = $("#input").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: baseUrl + "query?v=20150910",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
                },
                data: JSON.stringify({ q: text, lang: "en" }),
                success: function(data) {
                    setResponse(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
                },
                error: function() {
                    setResponse("Internal Server Error");
                }
            });
            setResponse("Loading...");
        }
```

check this Gist for the complete code.
https://gist.github.com/artemgoncharuk/b31b6a656c954a2866e8